# networking what type of socket to use to recieve all data

Tags: networking

in networking what type of socket should i use to guarantee that the receiving application has received all of the data in order?

Comment: You can find this in your networking textbook. http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Networks-Andrew-S-Tanenbaum/dp/0133499456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the TCP socket (sometimes called reliable). A sample code of creating such socket:

```
SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```